# Is "the Kozak in a stormy meadow" part of a traditional song?

Tags: poetry, ukrainian-language, taras-shevchenko, the-complete-kobzar

The Taras Shevchenko poem *To Osnovianenko* (in *The Complete Kobzar*, translated by Peter Fedynsky) has the following lines:

> I ramble through the snow 
> And to myself I sing:
> *The Kozak in a Stormy Meadow!*

Can someone explain the last line to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lines that you're referring to are, in [the original Ukrainian poem](https://www.ukrlib.com.ua/books/printit.php?tid=736#google_vignette) "До Основ'яненка" ("To Osnovianenko"):

> Блуджу в снігах та сам собі:
> "Ой не шуми, луже!"

A direct translation of this phrase, either [by itself](https://translate.google.com/?sl=auto&tl=en&text=%D0%91%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B6%D1%83%20%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%85%20%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%96%3A%20%20%0A%22%D0%9E%D0%B9%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%88%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B8%2C%20%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5!%22&op=translate) or [in the context of the whole poem](https://www-ukrlib-com-ua.translate.goog/books/printit.php?tid=736&_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en-US&_x_tr_pto=wapp), is given by Google Translate as either:

> I wander in the snow and to myself:
> "Oh, don't make noise, kid!"

or:

> I wander in the snow and say to myself:
> "Oh, don't make any noise, puddle!"

You haven't mentioned which translation you're using, but I assume these are the lines that you're asking about, given the "wander/ramble in/through the snow" (the only reference to snow in the whole poem). [This translation](https://taras-shevchenko.storinka.org/taras-shevchenko%27s-poem-to-osnovianenko-ukrainian-to-english-translation-by-c-h-andrusyshen-and-watson-kirkconnell.html) by С.H. Andrusyshen and Watson Kirkconnell (from [this book](https://shron2.chtyvo.org.ua/Shevchenko/The_Poetical_Works_of_Taras_Shevchenko_The_Kobzar_anhl.pdf?PHPSESSID=f167m2eu4uus1hsniel7bgkcd6)) renders the lines as:

> I roam in grief, and softly sing
> As meadow-grasses bend.

Thus, it seems that the line "The Kozak in a Stormy Meadow" is **an invention of the translator** of the version that you read. My best guess as to its meaning, given that "kozak" is the Ukrainian word for [cossack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cossacks), is the traditional Ukrainian song **"Ой у лузі червона калина"** ("Oh, the Red Viburnum in the Meadow"): you can read an English translation [here](https://www.ukrainianlessons.com/song-chervona-kalyna/) and listen to the original [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZUXMeSp7Y_A). The title isn't exactly as your translator gives it, but whoever that is is clearly not committed to exact translations anyway. It's a popular Ukrainian song featuring a stormy meadow and historically connected with cossacks/Kozaks, so it's my best guess as to what the translator was referring to.

Comment: "Chervona kalyna" is a younger song than this poem

Comment: @Andra Apparently it originates from a 17th-century Cossack song, do we have any more information about the latter?

Comment: may Ukrainians correct me, I read Wiki and anyway this also - https://ihavequestions.com.ua/question/skilky-rokiv-pisni-oy-u-luzi-chervona-kalyna/

Comment: ok, here https://www.istpravda.com.ua/columns/2022/04/23/161248/ it is mentioned about XVII century